# Unable to use createQuery() in typescript

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, hierarchy, children, createquery

I am trying to create a query using the following- 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2#method_createQuery

I am developing a vsts extension using above. This is the code-

```
import { QueryHierarchyItem  } from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/Contracts";
var postedQuery = [

    {
        "children": [],
        "clauses": {
            "field": {
                "referenceName": "System.WorkItemType",
                "name": "Work Item Type",
                "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.WorkItemType"
            },
            "operator": {
                "referenceName": "SupportedOperations.Equals",
                "name": "="
            },
            "value": "Bug"
        },

        "columns": [
            {
                "referenceName": "System.Id",
                "name": "ID",
                "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.Id"
            },
            {
                "referenceName": "System.Title",
                "name": "Title",
                "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.Title"
            },
            {
                "referenceName": "System.State",
                "name": "State",
                "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.State"
            }
        ],
        "createdBy": {
            "id": "d291b0c4-a05c-4ea6-8df1-4b41d5f39eff",
            "displayName": "Jamal Hartnett <fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com>"
        },
        "createdDate": "2016-06 - 01T16: 58:56.64Z",
        "filterOptions": "WorkItems",
        "hasChildren": false,
        "id": "df60fdf6-3b5f-4928-aae8-29ee63df6e31",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "isFolder": false,
        "isInvalidSyntax": true,
        "isPublic": false,
        "lastModifiedBy": {
            "id": "d291b0c4-a05c-4ea6-8df1-4b41d5f39eff",
            "displayName": "Jamal Hartnett <fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com>"
        },
        "lastModifiedDate": "2016-06 - 01T16: 58:56.64Z",
        "name": "All Bugs",
        "path": "Shared Queries",
        "queryType": "flat",
        "sortColumns": [
            {
                "field": {
                    "referenceName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
                    "name": "Priority",
                    "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"
                },
                "descending": false
            },
            {
                "field": {
                    "referenceName": "System.CreatedDate",
                    "name": "Created Date",
                    "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields/System.CreatedDate"
                },
                "descending": true
            }
        ],

        "wiql": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc",


    }

]



 let queryPath = "Shared Queries";
    let Query: QueryHierarchyItem = postedQuery;

   client.createQuery(Query, "Team_P1", queryPath).then((wi) => {


    },
        (query) => {


        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can refer to Cyril’s answer.

Secondly, you can refer to this code instead:

```
let Query:any={
            name:"Api Query",
            wiql: "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
        };
let queryPath = "Shared Queries";


   client.createQuery(Query, "Team_P1", queryPath).then((wi) => {


    },
        (query) => {


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the tsc compiler will truncate the error message to 100 characters.

You can change it by setting `"noErrorTruncation": true` in the `compilerOptions` property of your *tsconfig.json* file.

See [Typescript Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for more details

The error message is now (after beautifying)

> 'Type ' 
>    `{
>         "children": any[];
>         "clauses": {
>             "field": {
>                 "referenceName": string;
>                 "name": string;
>                 "url": string;
>             };
>             "operator": {
>                 "referenceName": string;
>                 "name": string;
>             };
>             "value": string;
>         };
>         "columns": {
>             "referenceName": string;
>             "name": string;
>             "url": string;
>         }[];
>         "createdBy": {
>             "id": string;
>             "displayName": string;
>         };
>         "createdDate": string;
>         "filterOptions": string;
>         "hasChildren": boolean;
>         "id": string;
>         "isDeleted": boolean;
>         "isFolder": boolean;
>         "isInvalidSyntax": boolean;
>         "isPublic": boolean;
>         "lastModifiedBy": {
>             "id": string;
>             "displayName": string;
>         };
>         "lastModifiedDate": string;
>         "name": string;
>         "path": string;
>         "queryType": string;
>         "sortColumns": {
>             "field": {
>                 "referenceName": string;
>                 "name": string;
>                 "url": string;
>             };
>             "descending": boolean;
>         }[];
>         "wiql": string;
>       }[]`
>   ' is not assignable to type 'QueryHierarchyItem'.
>   Property '`children`' is missing in type [type repeated].
>     '

you declared `postedQuery` as an array `[]` whereas `QueryHierarchyItem` that's why property `children` is missing.

If you remove the array you will have new error messages with missing properties and so on.

By the way, based on [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#create-a-query) it doesn't look you need to create the whole object, you can create an empty object an assigning the required parameters.

```
let queryPath = "Shared Queries";
let query: <QueryHierarchyItem>{};
query.Name = 'Query Name'; 
query.wiql = '...'

client.createQuery(query, "Team_P1", queryPath)
      .then(wi => {
          console.log(wi);             
      }, q => {
          console.log(q);
      });
```

Comment: If the solution is working, please mark the answer as accepter, it will help others to find this answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information :)